# Searching HTML document for specific content no longer working

Tags: jquery, dom

I had a solution working but my server actually crashed this afternoon. 
Unfortunately, I didn't check in my working code. I got help from StackOverflow earlier in the day to get my code working and I've used the answer from my previous post, but it's no longer working. =(

Anyways. What I was trying to do was locate a label that had some text in it, and assign and ID to the element.

Here's the HTML:

```
<DT>change me dynamically</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
```

What I want to do to this code via query is make it look like this:

```
<DT id="contactTypeLabel">Phone Number</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
```

Here's the code I was using earlier:

```
$('body >DT:contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
    var exp = /change me dynamically/;
    alert("nodevalue is:" + this.nodeValue);       
    if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {
        var $parent = $(this).parent().attr('id', 'contactTypeLabel');
        $parent.text(function(_, text){
           return  text.replace(exp, "Phone Number");
        }); 
    }
});
```

The alert never happens. If I broaden the search by doing this:

```
$('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
```

Then I get numerous alert statements. But in reality, I only have one element with the text "change me dynamically".

Sorry to the guys that helped me earlier. I really did try to review all the notes from before... but I can't seem to find the bug. It's been a rough day and I'm pretty harassed so I've probably missed something simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your DT an immediate child of the body tag? Your body>DT selector is saying it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description

`DT` and `DD` tags are usually nested inside `DL` tags. The selector:

```
$('body >DT:contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
```

Only looks for `DT` nodes which are direct descendants of the `body` node, skipping any that are inside of another node. However, the following snippet widens the scope to **any** node that contains that text:

```
$('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
```

### Solutions

What you're probably looking for is one that will look for `DT` nodes inside a `DL` that contain that text:

```
$('body DL>DT:contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
```

Or simply any `DT` node containing the text:

```
$('body DT:contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
```

### Information

For more information, see the article on the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Comment: thanks for the explanation!  that worked.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the site allows.  thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. It also seems redundant that you use the jQuery `:contains()` selector but then also do a regular expression test for the same exact thing. You really only need one or the other. You can also probably speed up the selector by just assigning all `DT` nodes the `class="contactTypeLabel"` and then selecting `$('.contactTypeLabel')`. Don't forget that an `id` should be unique, but classes can (and should) be used for multiple elements. There's some other logic I don't understand in your function too, like the fact that you're doing this in an `each()` loop.

Comment: corion, i was "given" this answer in a prev. post.  I'm a newbie to jquery.  but I have to do some similar logic multiple times, for different labels.  I need to locate them by the text they contain and then assign ids.

Comment: if you can post an example that's more efficient, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: It depends on where you're getting your data from, but the best solution for what you're trying to do would probably be to dynamically create the pairs of `DT` and `DD` nodes while looping through the array of data. There's not a lot of value gained by searching and replacing nodes that already exist. It would be better to construct the contents of the `DL` outside of the DOM and then replace the contents of your entire `DL` in a single call. The fewer changes/queries to the DOM, the better your code will be.

Comment: @markli Specifically, you will probably want to create an array of [`<DT>Term</DT>`, `<DD>Definition</DD>`, `<DT>Term2</DT>`, ...] in a loop. Next, use the `.join("")` function on them to turn it into a single string. Then, use jQuery's [`html()` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) to replace the entire `DL`. e.g. `$('#idOfDL').html(strTheJoinedString)`